# JMSTwigJsBundle doesn't compile

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, configuration, twig

In a search to optimize the possibility of my application made with symfony2, I choose the JMSTwigJsBundle to allow the usage of twig template both frontend or backend.

I use composer to install bundles and symfony (it is the 2.7.3 version)

I began to follow a tutorial who bring me to add both  FOSJsRoutingBundle and JMSTwigJsBundle. The first one, installed first, work perfectly, but the second brought me different kinds of problem, beginning with "Uncaught ReferenceError: goog is not defined". I resolved it by adding the following content :

these two lines on `app/autoloader.php` as described in the official documentation ( http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSTwigJsBundle ):

```
$loader->add('JMS', __DIR__.'/../vendor/jms/twig-js-bundle');
$loader->add('TwigJs', __DIR__.'/../vendor/jms/twig-js/src');
```

The `app/AppKernel.php` is set with the following line :

```
new JMS\TwigJsBundle\JMSTwigJsBundle(),
```

I also add to my `app/config.yml` these lines :

```
Filters:
twig_js:
resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/jms/twig-js-bundle/JMS/TwigJsbundle/Resources/config/services.xml"
apply_to: "\.twig$"
```

So, we can found inside my `layout.html.twig` the following lines

```
{% javascripts
    'js/fos_js_routes.js'
    '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/jms/twig-js/twig.js
    '@NameSpaceNameBundle/Resources/views/customFolder/example.html.twig'%}
    <script language="javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

And, thank to the filters on the config file, we don't need to add the filter line.

These modifications are from : https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTwigJsBundle/pull/13 post 3

I also do modifications presentend here : https://github.com/schmittjoh/twig.js/issues/35 post 2 :

> I found a way to fix this issue by copyng the file
>   /Symfony/vendor/bundles/JMS/TwigJsBundle/Resources/config/services.xml
>   to
>   /Symfony/vendor/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle/Resources/config/filters/twig_js.xml
>   and changing the service id from twig_js.assetic_filter to
>   assetic.filter.twig_js.

Every of theses modifications bring me to a new error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %

on the created file "exemple.html.twig.js:1". For information, the twig file looks like :

```
{% twig_js name="example" %}
the html code
```

And the content generated on the new file is... exactly the same content than the twig's file.

So, please, what did I have to do to make it work ? Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work to and have a compiled version of any .twig, I had to include the "YUIcompressor" to the `app/config/config.yml` :

```
yui_css:
jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar"
yui_js
jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar"
```

and add the appropriate file to the associate path.

Then I add to the `layout.html.twig`

```
{% javascripts filter='?yui_js'
    'js/fos_js_routes.js'
    '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/jms/twig-js/twig.js
    '@NameSpaceNameBundle/Resources/views/customFolder/example.html.twig'%}
    <script language="javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Finally I use the app/console assets:install and app/console assetic:dump to check if they're is nothing wrong, refreshed and it was ok (at least for me).